# Clock aligned loop

Tags: c++, loops, time

I am polling a webcam in a while loop (c++), however the plan is to have this running on several independent systems with their own cameras. They will then return the frame with a timestamp so that I can get synchronized images. The problem is synchronization. Rather than trying to send out a trigger, I'd like to replace the while loop with something that is called in lockstep with the systems clock so I could do something like have a frame for each at exactly 12:55:01.

Is this possible?

edit: The time synchronization problem would be handled by NTP or similar. Also, each of the systems are identical.

Comment: This can be either a programming problem, *or* an infrastructure problem. Either you have a central server which all systems connect to, and that central system sends out a "take photo now" signal to the connected distributed systems, and that is a programming problem. *Or* you let each system be separate, and then keep their clock synchronized, and that is an infrastructure problem. Before this question can be answered (or moved to the correct Stackexchange site) you need to decide which way you want to go.

Comment: This is actually amazingly tricky.  See http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time and http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time